# How to POST a fine-tuning job to OpenAI API using the correct file format?

Tags: rest, curl, openai-api

I am new to the OpenAI API and I am trying to understand [fine-tuning](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning) to use [the API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/fine-tuning).

I checked what finetuning files I have available using this request in [VS Code Rest Client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client):

```http
GET https://api.openai.com/v1/files
Authorization: Bearer {{key}}
```

Here is part of the Response:

```json
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "file",
      "id": "file-2FLvF7VJSBsEOFSwJAf1XXXX",
      "purpose": "fine-tune",
      "filename": "mydata.jsonl",
      "bytes": 493,
      "created_at": 1697459301,
      "status": "processed",
      "status_details": null
    },
    {
....
```

Apparently, I have a file object with id "file-2FLvF7VJSBsEOFSwJAf1XXXX" (last four characters I want to keep secret) for a "purpose" named "fine-tune". Sounds great, so let's use that in a call.

```http
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/fine_tuning/jobs
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{key}}

{
  "training_file": "file-2FLvF7VJSBsEOFSwJAf1XXXX",
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo"
}
```

This is the result:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "File 'file-2FLvF7VJSBsEOFSwJAf1XXXX' is in prompt-completion format. The model gpt-3.5-turbo-0613 requires data in the chat-completion format.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": "invalid_file_format"
  }
}
```

I got the error. That data is indeed in prompt-completion instead of chat completion format:

```json
{"prompt": "What is the closest planet to the sun?", "completion": "The closest planet to the sun is Mercury."}
{"prompt": "How many moons does Mars have?", "completion": "Mars has two moons."}
{"prompt": "What is the largest planet in our solar system?", "completion": "The largest planet in our solar system is Jupiter."}
{"prompt": "What is the main component of Saturn's rings?", "completion": "The main component of Saturn's rings is ice particles, with some rocky debris and dust."}
```

However, it is still not clear how to fix this. The chat completion format is simply not accepted. Here is how I discovered this using this jsonl file

```json
{"chat": "Translate the following English text to French: 'Hello, how are you?'", "completion": "Bonjour, comment ça va?"}
{"chat": "What's the capital of France?", "completion": "Paris"}
{"chat": "Solve for x: 2x + 5 = 11", "completion": "x = 3"}
```

which I tried to upload by running this in my wsl (Ubuntu) console:

```bash
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/files   -H "Authorization: Bearer [MY_KEY]"   -F purpose="fine-tune"   -F file="@fineTune.jsonl"
```

giving this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unexpected file format, expected either prompt/completion pairs or chat messages.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
}
```

So how can I possibly solve this?

All I want to is to get a call like this:

```http
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/fine_tuning/jobs
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{key}}

{
  "training_file": "file-2FLvF7VJSBsEOFSwJAf1XXXX",
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo"
}
```

working..... But I don't succeed. So please help me getting this working. Please come up with a fully working example.

---

**UPDATE**

Appararently, I need to use gpt-3.5-turbo-0613 instead but that is still not solving the problem.

To help me, I need a fully working example. I do not need an explanation. It is clear for me how to do it in theory. However, when I try it in reality with real curl calls. It is not working at all.

All I want is to get a HTTP Statuscode 200 from this call. So please give my a fully working example with curl calls.

```bash
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/fine_tuning/jobs \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer {{key}}" \
  -d '{
    "training_file": "file-2FLvF7VJSBsEOFSwJAf1XXXX",
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613"
  }'
```

But this always gives me errors like this.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "File 'file-2FLvF7VJSBsEOFSwJAf1XXXX' is in prompt-completion format. The model gpt-3.5-turbo-0613 requires data in the chat-completion format.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": "invalid_file_format"
  }
}
```

Logically, I need to upload a file to do so. I do this with this call first:

```bash
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/files \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer {{key}}" \
  -F purpose="fine-tune" \
  -F file="@chatCompletion.jsonl"
```

I tried these jsonl files:

```json
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Tell me a joke."}]}
```

```json
{  "role": "user", "content": "What is the average temperature in New York city in January?" }
{  "role": "assistant", "content": "The average temperature in New York City in January is around 32°F (0°C)."}
{  "role": "user",     "content": "Is that safe for humans" }
```

```json
{"messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Tell me about the Eiffel Tower."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Tell me about the Eiffel Tower."}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Eiffel Tower is a wrought-iron lattice tower located in Paris, France. It was constructed in 1889 as the entrance arch for the 1889 World's Fair and has since become one of the most recognizable structures in the world."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "How tall is it?"}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "How tall is it?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Eiffel Tower is approximately 324 meters (1,063 feet) tall, including its antennas."}]}
```

```json
{"messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "How does photosynthesis work?"}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "What is the capital of France?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "The capital of France is Paris."}, {"role": "user", "content": "How tall is the Eiffel Tower?"}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Can you give me a recipe for chocolate chip cookies?"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The conversation chat format is required to fine-tune `gpt-3.5-turbo`

```json
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "Marv is a factual chatbot that is also sarcastic."}, {"role": "user", "content": "What's the capital of France?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Paris, as if everyone doesn't know that already."}]}
```

```bash
curl -X POST https://api.openai.com/v1/files \
-H 'authorization: Bearer <token>' \
-F file="@file.jsonl" \
-F purpose="fine-tune"
```

After the file is processed, you can create a fine-tuning model.

Comment: Gives HTTP Statuscode 400. The file content you provided is json, not jsonl

Comment: can you post your file contents?  jsonl requires each json object to be on a single line

Comment: I just updated my POST with concrete file contents. What I need now is a fully working example.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem! Can you change ./  to @  ? This is needed to make it work on Linux. After you did that, your answer is fully correct and I'll approve so you'll get the bounty points.

Comment: I updated it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JSONL file contents should be like below

```
{"idea" : "Innovation"}
{"idea" : "Innovation 1"}
{"idea" : "Innovation 2"}
{"idea" : "Innovation 3"}
```

Now, let's talk about gpt-3.5-turbo engine required format

```
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "What is Laravel?"} , {"role": "assistant", "content": "Laravel is a free, open-source PHP web framework used for web application development."}]}
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "How do you install Laravel?"},{"role": "assistant", "content": "Laravel can be installed using Composer. Run `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-name`."},]}
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "What is Eloquent ORM?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Eloquent is Laravel's built-in ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) for working with databases using an elegant syntax."}]}
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Explain Laravel Blade templates."}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Blade is the templating engine in Laravel. It provides a clean, concise syntax for writing templates with features like template inheritance and control structures."},]}
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "How do you create a migration in Laravel?"},{"role": "assistant", "content": "To create a migration, run `php artisan make:migration MigrationName`. Then, define the schema in the generated migration file and run `php artisan migrate`."}]}
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "What is the purpose of Laravel middleware?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Middleware in Laravel provides a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application. It is often used for authentication, logging, or modifying the request/response."}]}
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Explain the concept of Laravel facades."}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Facades in Laravel provide a static interface to classes available in the application's service container. They offer a convenient way to access services without using dependency injection."}]}
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "How do you define routes in Laravel?"},{"role": "assistant", "content": "Routes in Laravel are defined in the `routes/web.php` file or `routes/api.php` for web and API routes, respectively. Use functions like `Route::get` or `Route::post` to define routes."}]}
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "What is the purpose of Laravel's Artisan console?"},{"role": "assistant", "content": "Artisan is the command-line interface included with Laravel. It provides helpful commands for various tasks, such as migrating databases, running jobs, and generating boilerplate code."}]}
{"messages":[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a knowledgeable assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Tell me about Laravel Mix."},{"role": "assistant", "content": "Laravel Mix is a fluent JavaScript and SASS compilation tool. It simplifies asset compilation and provides a clean, expressive API over complex, bundling and minification processes."}]}
```

It requires messages as single prompt & answer identification. and assign an array with three objects.

```
1. system role & system content
2. user role & user question as prompt
3. assistant role & content as an answer to the user question.
```

These examples for the gpt-3.5-turbo

To Use Davinci-002 you have to change the JSONL content

```
{"prompt" : "What is Laravel?", "completion": "Laravel is a free, open-source PHP web framework."}
{"prompt": "What is the purpose of Laravel's Artisan console?" , "completion": "Artisan is the command-line interface included with Laravel. It provides helpful commands for various tasks, such as migrating databases, running jobs, and generating boilerplate code."}
```

Happy Coding.